# How do you dictate the position of communities in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm using igraph in R.  I want to assign coordinates to the vertices within a membership.  According to [this](http://www.r-bloggers.com/experiments-with-igraph/) page, it is possible to dictate the colour of all the vertices within a membership by doing the following:

Dataset is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ss18LQyoQrQ0lmckJ4aVRyVGs):

```
cat<-read.csv(file="SIMP_adj.csv",header=F,sep=",")
cat<-as.matrix(cat)
g <- graph.adjacency(cat, weighted=T, mode = "undirected")
fg<-cluster_fast_greedy(g,merges=T,modularity=T,membership=T)
V(g)$membership <- fg$membership
V(g) [ membership == 1 ]$color <- "green"
```

So I've tried to modify it for my purposes:

```
m<-matrix(data=1:10,ncol=2)
V(g) [ membership == 1 ]$layout <- m
```

I get the following warning message (and no coordinate changes to my plot)

```
In vattrs[[name]][index] <- value :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

So I changed it to

```
V(g) [ membership == 1 ]$layout <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

This eliminates the warning message, but the plot coordinates don't change (perhaps obviously).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

igraph decides the positions of the vertices based on the matrix or layout algorithm that you pass to the `plot()` function when you plot the graph. By default, the layout algorithm is `layout_nicely`. `layout_nicely` allows us to control the graph layout in more than one way:

1. Construct a matrix with two columns and N rows that contains the desired coordinates, and assign that matrix to the `layout` attribute of the *graph*, *not* the individual vertices.
2. Assign vertex attributes named `x` and `y` to the *vertices*. (So, `layout` as a vertex attribute won't work, but you can use `x` and `y` separately).

Answer (score 0):

#give vertices that belong to community one a set of coordinates

```
one<-as_ids(V(g)[membership==1])
one<-induced.subgraph(g,one)
one<-layout_as_star(one)
```

#get vertices belonging to community two a set of coordinates

```
two<-as_ids(V(g)[membership==2])
two<-induced.subgraph(g,two)
two<-layout_as_star(two)
```

#change the position of community one so it is not plotted over community two.

```
one<-one+1
```

#combine the two sets of coordinates

```
black<-rbind(one, two)
plot(g,layout=black)
```